# Drawing Rectangle in Java Shows Pixel Anomaly

Tags: java, swing

I have a very simple java program that draws a rectangle but when I closely examine the rendered shape, I see two extra pixels that shouldn't be there ...

[image]
You can see one extra pixel at below left and one at below right.

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-BIT using JDK 1.8.0.   Here is the program ...

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class JavaBug {

    public JavaBug() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        frame.add( new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.drawRect(50, 50, 20, 20); 
                }
            });

            frame.setSize(400, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible( true );
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
            new JavaBug();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps include a screenshot?

Comment: It is kind of hard to see, but if you magnify it, the pixels stand out

Comment: What OS and Java version are you using?  Windows 7, Java 6 & 7 - no issues

Comment: `paintComponent` should be `protected` and not `public`

Comment: Just ran it with java 1.8.0-ea-b93 on Win 7 x64 no problems visible here.

Comment: *UPDATE* I uninstalled Java 8 and it now works (Under 7). I will try to re-install JDK 8 to reproduce ...

Comment: OK, I have just confirmed it is reproducible with latest build of JDK 8 (I just downloaded and re-installed it) ... Problem goes away with prior version

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue

Comment: The usual suspects: Do you have an up-to-date graphics card driver?

Comment: Does this issue also arise when setting rendering hints on the `Graphics2D` object like following: `g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);` ?

Comment: @Marco13 This is a new laptop (ThinkPad T440)

Comment: @Awfully Awesome, I attribute this to version 8. I un-ininstalled it and currently using version 7 and it works now. Since version 8 is a pre-release, I will stick with this current version (I have sent Oracle a bug notice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For sake of an answer in case anyone comes across this question**

The problem seemed to be with the Java 8 pre-release version. This code works fine with Java 7.

*Note: This conclusion was taken from the comments section and I did not contribute to the answer. :-)*

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. I've tested. It's a Java 8 Bug.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only confirmation of the bug as others have reported they see no problem.